# Alterando cores de botões após clique

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa tarde amigos, estou iniciando os estudos em python e preciso fazer um trabalho utilizando tkinter. Tenho 64 botões e devo mudar suas cores de acordo com o clique do usuário. Ele tem 6 opções de cores, e quando ele clicar em uma delas, o primeiro dos 64 botões tem que obter a cor clicada, e assim sucessivamente, até que os 64 botões estejam coloridos. Contudo, meu código só está alterando o último dos 64 botões, e não estou conseguindo corrigir. Deixarei o print do programa e o código. Desde já, obrigado. [image: Tela que deve ser corrigida]

***Função chamada***

```
    def getCorAtual(corAtual):
        desenho.configure(bg=corAtual)
        print(corAtual)
        boxCorAtual.configure(bg=corAtual)
```

***Botões da esquerda***

```
    cor1 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#ffffff', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#ffffff'))
    cor1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    cor2 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#000000', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#000000'))
    cor2.grid(column=1, row=0)
    cor3 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#ff0000', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#ff0000'))
    cor3.grid(column=0, row=1)
    cor4 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#0000ff', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#0000ff'))
    cor4.grid(column=1, row=1)
    cor5 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#00ff00', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#00ff00'))
    cor5.grid(column=0, row=2)
    cor6 = tk.Button(coresWrap, bg='#ffff00', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: 
    getCorAtual('#ffff00'))
    cor6.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

***Criação da janela***

```
    containerDesenho = tk.Label(janela, bg='#e3e3e3')
    containerDesenho.place(x=200, y=0, width=600, height=800)

    tela = tk.Label(containerDesenho, bg='#e3e3e3')
    tela.place(width=600, height=700, x=30, y=10)
```

***Botões que devem ficar coloridos***

```
    for i in range(1, 9):
        for j in range(1, 9):
            desenho = tk.Button(tela, bg='white', width=8, height=4)
            desenho["command"] = lambda x=j, y=i: getBotao(x, y)
            desenho.grid(column=j, row=i)
```

Comment: Oi, a ideia é que quando um botão for clicado do lado esquerdo todos os do lado direito devem ser coloridos com a cor do botão pressionado?

Comment: @WilliamTeixeira exatamente isso, ir colorindo da esquerda pra direita até que todos fiquem coloridos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explicação

Basicamente ***quando você cria vários botões atribuídos a uma única variável você não poderá acessá-los e editá-los posteriormente***.
Ex.: Se você define:

```
a = 1
print(a)

Resultado: 1
```

Mas se você define:

```
a = 1
a = 2
print(a)

Resultado: 2
```

A mesma coisa acontece para um loop

```
a = 0
for c in range(4):
    a = c
    print(c, end = ' - ')

print(c)

Resultado: 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 3
```

Perceba que ao sair do loop quando você exibe a variável `a` na tela ele mostra somente o último valor, que foi 3, isso significa que uma variável é limitada, e está restrita somente a um valor, ***é como uma caixinha que só cabe um item, ao definir*** `a = 1` ***a caixinha está com o item*** `1`, ***mas se em seguida eu defino*** `a = 2` ***a caixinha deixará de ter o item*** `1` ***e passará a conter o item*** `2`, ***já uma lista é como se fosse uma caixa maior, onde eu posso colocar os 2 itens (ou mais, dependendo da sua necessidade)***, `lista = [1, 2]`, ***você é quem define o tamanho da lista***. Agora vou deixar de papo furado e ir direto para a solução!

### Solução

O caminho mais viável que achei foi usando listas. Para começar você terá que declarar uma lista com mais 8 listas dentro, basicamente cada lista contida dentro da lista principal é uma linha da área de desenho, ficaria assim: `tabela = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`, a lista "tabela" é toda a área do desenho, e as listas contidas dentro dela são as linhas na área do desenho, ex.: `tabela[0] == Linha1`. O próximo passo seria mudar a forma que cria os botões, ao invés de criar botões atribuídos a uma variável, ele iria adicionando e armazenando os botões em ordem na lista "tabela", assim:

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        tabela[i].append(Button(root, bg = '#ffffff', width = 8, height = 4))
        tabela[i][j].config(command = lambda x = j, y = i: getBotao(x, y))
        tabela[i][j].grid(column = j, row = i)
```

Em seguida você criaria 2 variáveis globais

```
cont_column = 0
cont_line = 0
```

De preferência no início do programa, fora de qualquer função

O `cont_column` vai contar as colunas e o `cont_line` as linhas

A função `getCorAtual` ficaria assim:

```
def getCorAtual(corAtual):
    # Específica que as variáveis são globais
    global tabela
    global boxCorAtual
    global cont_column
    global cont_line

    # Se chegou no fim da área do desenho ele começa a substituir as cores do início
    if cont_line == len(tabela) - 1 and cont_column == len(tabela[cont_line]):
        cont_line = 0
        cont_column = 0

    # Se chegou no fim da linha ele irá pular para a próxima linha e começar a preencher as colunas do zero
    if cont_column == len(tabela[cont_line]):
        cont_column = 0
        cont_line += 1

    tabela[cont_column][cont_line].configure(bg=corAtual)
    print(corAtual)
    boxCorAtual.configure(bg=corAtual)
    cont_column += 1
```

### Espero ter ajudado. Bons estudos!

Comment: Paulo, era exatamente disso que eu precisava, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!